# Where should I be rubbing my Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon-x-y, pokemon-sixth-generation

When I first started playing with Pokemon'Amie, my Froakie just absolutely loved getting his tummy rubbed.

But now when I go in to play with him, he frowns at me when I administer the belly rubs.

In general, where should I be rubbing my frog to increase his affection? Is it the same for each Pokémon species, or does each individual 'mon have a special spot they like rubbed?

Comment: Why don't you just have a seat right there...

Comment: If it's a Pikachu, avoid touching its cheek, unless you like electric shocks ;)

Comment: Wherever it makes them... [happy](https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/q71/1382917_655630151122516_1594848224_n.jpg)

Comment: Bring me back to Kingdom Hearts: Dream Drop distance...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you play with sound on, the rubbing noise (the 'wipwipwip' sound) changes in pitch as you find 'sweet spots' or 'bad spots'. *The **higher** the pitch, the more the Pokemon enjoys it*.

Short of facial expressions/body language, this has been the easiest way to figure out the sweet spots for me.

There is a thread over on [GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/696959-pokemon-x/67570168?page=1) where people have been sharing good/bad areas to rub as well, if you still cannot find a good place to rub, it may be listed there.

Answer (score 13):

From my experience, there is no one guaranteed place that's good for rubbing (either Pokemon or otherwise...) There is one thing you can do to make sure raising your Pokemon's affection though.

When you touch your stylus to the screen to rub your Pokemon, watch their expressions before you actually rub. Whenever their eyes form an upside-down U, that's a good spot to rub. Watch out if they make a pained or annoyed expression though, that's generally not a good spot.

For Pokemon lacking a way to express facial expressions, pay attention to body language. For example, if Butterfree tilts its head back/up it generally means that the Pokemon is enjoying the rub. If it seems to not move at all, it's generally a bad spot.

Comment: Okay, that works for Froakie. What about my Beedril, Steve who lacks eyes? And mouth, come to think of it...

Comment: In my experience, each Pokemon has a generally good area, and the best spot varies a little bit within that area from time to time.